# Package http does not include in React Native as well as Node standard library

Tags: node.js, react-native, http, fetch, expo

When i try to `expo start` expo application, i get following message:

```
The package at "node_modules\fetch\lib\fetch.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "http". It failed because React Native does not include the Node standard library. Read more at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq/#can-i-use-nodejs-packages-with-expo
```

Fetch package is installed, how do i add node standard library to my expo project? I need to use http to call fetch.

Comment: you really don't need fetch package. Fetch is available as is. https://reactnative.dev/docs/network#using-fetch. remove the fetch package that is installed and check.

Comment: check:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60837915/expo-unable-to-resolve-fetch