# expo Unable to resolve "fetch"

Tags: node.js, react-native, fetch, expo

I am trying to run an expo project, (react-native) but when i run the project, i get following result:

```
Unable to resolve "fetch" from "src\components\MyScreen\Screen.js"
```

Fetch should not be a nodejs standard feature? What should i do to run fetch with the project?

Also, if i try to `yarn add fetch`, i get a different error.

```
The package at "node_modules\fetch\lib\fetch.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "http". It failed because React Native does not include the Node standard library. Read more at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq/#can-i-use-nodejs-packages-with-expo
```

Am i missing something?

Here is where im calling fetch:

```
fetch(`${API_URL()}/orders`, requestInfo)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    } else {
      throw new Error("Erro ao registrar endereço!");
    }
  })
  .then(currentUser => {
    this.setState({ loading: false });
    alert("Pedido realizado com sucesso!");
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Products");
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.setState({ loading: false });
    alert(error.message);
  });
```

Comment: can you add the code a little bit?

Comment: sure, here it go

Comment: you are not importing `fetch` from anywhere right?

Comment: yes, i am......

Comment: but I mean you don't need to import fetch from anywhere. just use it

Comment: const fetch = require('fetch');

Comment: yeah don't import it. Just use it.

Comment: thanks, that was it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Expo doc](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/network/#using-fetch) you don't need to import anything. Just use `fetch` in the code.

> ```
> import React from 'react';
> import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View } from 'react-native';
>
> export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {
>   constructor(props) {
>     super(props);
>     this.state = { isLoading: true };
>   }
>
>   componentDidMount() {
>     return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
>       .then(response => response.json())
>       .then(responseJson => {
>         this.setState(
>           {
>             isLoading: false,
>             dataSource: responseJson.movies,
>           },
>           function() {}
>         );
>       })
>       .catch(error => {
>         console.error(error);
>       });
>   }
>
>   render() {
>     return (
>       ....
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```